# I need a "click" sound program on my keyboard to type more easily

Tags: software-installation, sound, keyboard

How do I install the program TICKEYS on Ubuntu 17.04?

"Tickeys" gives several sounds whenever a key is struck, from bubbles to typewriter to a mechanical, loud *thunk* sound. With my physical disability, the mechanical thunk is best.

The closest I've found is:

https://github.com/BillBillBillBill/Tickeys-linux; but i must be missing something because I can't find the correct string to get what I need.  Can anybody help?

~

Comment: Look at the README file.   Warning: It's not software that's in the Ubuntu repositories, so the support for it here will be very limited.

Comment: Hmm,  I dont care about suppport; only that it works as it did18 months or so  ago.  There is a "typewriter pytjon script that will do inthemeantimr. if i hhave to make-do, well, so beit.....

Comment: Did you try the instructions at https://github.com/BillBillBillBill/Tickeys-linux/blob/master/README_en_US.md#install? Did they work? If not, what was the issue? If yes, please report back so I or someone else can write a proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can download it from link in [the official installation instructions](https://github.com/BillBillBillBill/Tickeys-linux/blob/master/README_en_US.md) and then run command if you download the 64 version on terminal after you go to the folder that contain the package you download:

```
sudo dpkg -i tickeys_0.2.5_amd64.deb
```